# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error for cross platform

Tags: ajax, spring, cors

Hi I am trying to post some information on ajax call with cross domain. unfortunately i am getting below error.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://prodservices.apps.h2radio.com:8080/util-services/contributor/feedback. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://rivetnewsradio.com' is therefore not allowed access

I have searched for the above error and i have integrated below code in filter.

```
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    //response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, x-requested-with, my-cool-header");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
     chain.doFilter(req, res);
```

even I am getting same error i don't know how to resolve it. can any one give me the trick to get on.

Answer (score 0):

`*` won't work as `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` When `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` is set to `true`. So, try specifying the exact base URL, e.g. `http://localhost:9000`.

Instead of hardcoding the URL, you could use a property. If multiple sites could access your server, then a common practice is to get the site's base URL dynamically and checking it against a whilelist. I have it like this:

```
String origin = request.getHeader("Origin");

response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
ArrayUtils.contains(properties.getAllowedOrigins(), origin) ?
    origin : properties.getDefaultApplicationUrl());
```

It wouldn't be considered a good practice, but if you must allow all URLs, just replace the `*` with `request.getHeader("Origin")`.

Comment: Glad if it helped. If, you may like to accept the answer (by clicking on the tick) and upvote it (by clicking on the up arrow).